# How to seach all value nearly exact in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When I use `userInfos.find({username:"John ABC"})` I need to get all people with "John" or ABC occurence.

Here is my code :

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:String,
    password:String,
});

const userInfos = mongoose.model('userInfos', userSchema);
```

What is the best way to do this

Comment: should "doe john" be matched ?

Comment: yes it should be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/) feature of the MongoDB.

`$text` will tokenize the search string using whitespace and most punctuation as delimiters, and perform a logical OR of all such tokens in the search string.

First you need to create a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) for username field like this:

```
db.users.createIndex( { username: "text" } )
```

Then you can use the following code to search with **mongoose**:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/user");

router.get("/search", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await User.find({ $text: { $search: "John ABC" } }).select(
    "username"
  );

  res.send(result);
});
```

Let's say we have 5 users like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(\"5dea9bf903d65c440c1f169e\")",
    "username": "Jonas"
  },

  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5dea9bee03d65c440c1f169d"),
    "username": "ABCD"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5dea9be103d65c440c1f169c"),
    "username": "John ABC"
  },

  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5dea9bd503d65c440c1f169b"),
    "username": "ABC",
  },

  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5dea9bcd03d65c440c1f169a"),
    "username": "John"
  }
]
```

Search will return these 3 users:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5dea9bd503d65c440c1f169b",
        "username": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dea9be103d65c440c1f169c",
        "username": "John ABC"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dea9bcd03d65c440c1f169a",
        "username": "John"
    }
]
```

This shows clearly that the search worked.

You can even add text score and sort by score if you want like this:

```
router.get("/search", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await User.find(
    { $text: { $search: "John ABC" } },
    { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
  )
    .sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } })
    .select("username");

  res.send(result);
});
```

The result will have score like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5dea9be103d65c440c1f169c",
        "username": "John ABC",
        "score": 1.5
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dea9bcd03d65c440c1f169a",
        "username": "John",
        "score": 1.1
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dea9bd503d65c440c1f169b",
        "username": "ABC",
        "score": 1.1
    }
]
```

As you see, we have score field in the output, and users are sorted by score which is very useful.

If you use local MongoDB and if you have difficulty creating the text index, you can use [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#working-with-the-mongo-shell).

1. Open a command in the bin folder you installed MongoDB server. For example `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin`
2. type `mongo`
3. type `db`
4. Using your db name, let's say it is auth, type `use auth`
5. type `db.users.createIndex( { username: "text" } )`

And if you use MongoDB Atlas, you can create the text index like this:

1. Connect to the MongoDB atlas
2. Select your database, and collection
3. In the Indexes tab, click CREATE INDEX button
4. Create you index like this:
   [image]

Comment: wow thanks for awnser but i looking for way to do with mongoose

Comment: @luongvy this is mongoose, you see I query with mongoose model

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB [`$or` query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/) is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter the search using regex in your query.

```
userInfos.find({username:/(John|ABC)/g})
```

first the regex capture the group passed and check for first alternative which is 'John' here and then check for 'ABC'. don't forget the **g** flag which checks globally. you can use **i** flag for case insensitive which is much appreciated when user searches something.

Comment: if i have a string like const string = "John ABC"; how can i include this in to /()/g ?

Comment: the idea is to use the ```RegExp(str)``` constructor

Comment: yeah, you can use RegExp() construtor.. in your case, let str = "John ABC"; let res = str.split(" "); then  userInfos.find({username: new RegExp(\`(${res[0]}|${res[1]})\`, "ig")}); Try this out.

Comment: observe that when you have multiple variables, you should pass variables within parenthesis and separate them using '|' and pass them inside template literal (\`). second argument of RegExp is flags.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read more carefully SuleymanSah's answer. Text search is likely to be interesting, tokenization wise, **accent** wise, ...

But to "minimally" answer your question:

A useful practice is to use your mongo shell, test your queries, and when satisfying, use them for mongoose

Consider the minimal dataset:

```
[ "Johhn", "Johhn Doe", "John Doef", " Doef John", "John - Doe", "lol" ].forEach(x=>db.dum.insert({ username: x }))
db.dum.find()
> db.dum.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5deb4706b687c1e90e674099"), "username" : "Johhn" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5deb4706b687c1e90e67409a"), "username" : "Johhn Doe" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5deb4706b687c1e90e67409b"), "username" : "John Doef" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5deb4706b687c1e90e67409c"), "username" : " Doef John" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5deb4706b687c1e90e67409d"), "username" : "John - Doe" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5deb4706b687c1e90e67409e"), "username" : "lol" }
```

#### With an `$in` predicate

Basically, username must match one of the provided regexs

```
var str = 'doe john'
var lowerCase = 'i'
var choices = str.split(/[^\w]+/).map(w => new RegExp(w, lowerCase))
db.dum.find({ username: { $in: choices } })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5deb4706b687c1e90e67409a"), "username" : "Johhn Doe" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5deb4706b687c1e90e67409b"), "username" : "John Doef" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5deb4706b687c1e90e67409c"), "username" : " Doef John" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5deb4706b687c1e90e67409d"), "username" : "John - Doe" }
```

#### With an `$or` predicate

Basically one of the or predicates must return true, predicate here being `{username:someRegExp}`

```
var str = 'doe john'
var orPred = str.split(/[^\w]+/).map(w => ({ username: new RegExp(w, 'i') }))
db.dum.find({ $or: orPred })

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5deb4706b687c1e90e67409a"), "username" : "Johhn Doe" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5deb4706b687c1e90e67409b"), "username" : "John Doef" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5deb4706b687c1e90e67409c"), "username" : " Doef John" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5deb4706b687c1e90e67409d"), "username" : "John - Doe" }
```