# How i can query one part of a text and get it all using mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
Cliente.find({name: "Douglas"},(err,clientes)=>{
```

How I can perform this to return all results if that includes "Douglas" in the name?

Comment: You can use text index as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218495/11717458)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cliente.find({ name: { "$regex": "Douglas", "$options": "i" }},(err,clientes)=>{
```

I found this too. It works for me.